# Rotate hover-info in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

My current graph's hover-info is rotated slightly (see image below).  That is, when I hover over a bar, the hover text is rotated about 60 degrees from horizontal (e.g. see the 2nd bar down in the image).  How can I set the rotation to 0?

```
# sample data
tbl = data.frame(list_id = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), 
             main_count = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3),
             total = c(23,34,66,22,66,88,55,44,22,11,33,55,43,22,55))

plot_ly(tbl, type = "bar",
  y = main_count, x = total, group = list_id, orientation = "h") %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = ""), barmode = "stack")
```

[image: stacked bar chart with rotated labels]

Comment: If you want help with code you should show the code you are running. Create a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: In Chrome, when I right-click the topmost bar (so it's hover-text is visible), and choose "Inspect Element," I can see a few opening tags of this form: `<g class="hovertext" transform="translate(148.75,166.07)rotate(60)">`.  There are two other similar tags for the topmost bar.  You can manually edit the attribute to `rotate(0)`, just to see that it is controlling the rotation of each bit of text within that `<g>` tag.  Unfortunately, it's not immediately clear to me how to set the rotation from R.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the plotly(i'm using plotly.js), you can change the degree at : YANGLE: 60, however when they are close, it gonna cover each other if you wanna the hovertext to be up above or horizontal